# How to quick launch an app in the Dock via a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

In windows, it is easier to do cause there's shortcut via win+1 or ..., I'm wondering that I could do about the Mac, I did not find any stuff like that.

Answer (score 2):

On my laptop I press the Spotlight keyboard shortcut, type the first 3 letters of my app and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. It takes 1 second and *voilà*.